# C# linq Group by is nothing resulting the sql result set as SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, group-by, view

I have this very simple code in C# .NET Core to group by the information from a view.

```
var clients = await _clientsRepo.GetAsync();
var cliensPerRole = clients.GroupBy(n => n.Type)
                           .Select(n => new TotalPerType { Type = n.Key, Total = n.Count() })
                           .ToList();

return new DataInsightsViewModelClients
           {
               ClientsPerType = cliensPerRole,
               TotalClients = clients.Count(),
           };
```

When I was analysing the results, I discovery the SQL Server query

```
Select Type, Count(*) 
From ViewClient  
Group By Type
```

returns 3 lines and C# returns just 2.

```
Type       Count
---------------------
Clients    551
Landlord    35
RealEstate   1 --missed on C#
```

The only explanation I can imagine, it is something inside of C# with the property named `Type`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is someone else with this error?

Comment: Use debugger to see what's inside 'clients' before GroupBy executes

Comment: What is the type of `Type` property?

Comment: @Evk, it returns all 588 lines, as expected.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, it is a string, like I showed in the code.  Clientes, Landlord or realEstate

Comment: But your SQL query seems to result in 587 rows (551+35+1)

Comment: Probably you are reading a different database.  Check you connection string.  The connection string should match the Server and Instance you are using in the SQL Server (see SSMS login window).  Make sure your do not have in the connection string Attach Database.  The database is already attached to the server and you need use same database you are using with SSMS.

Comment: @Evk, the DB is in use. Still growing

Comment: Well IF you ensured with debugger that correct rows are returned in `clients` variable, and those rows contain one with "RealEstate" type, then I don't see how such result could happen. I'm quite sure that target row is just not in `clients` variable, but we have no idea why because we have no idea what `_clientsRepo.GetAsync()` does

Answer (score 0):

After a further investigation, I found the problem in my View key.

This is a small example of my data:

```
UserId  ClientType
    1   Landlord
    2   Clients
    3   Clients
    4   Clients    //duplicate
    4   RealEstate //duplicate
    5   Clients
```

SQL server query for it:

> Select ClientType, Count(*) from ViewClient Group by ClientType

Return:

```
Landlord   1
Clients.   4
RealEstate 1
```

But EF .net core using:

```
var clients = await _clientsRepo.GetAsync();
        var cliensPerRole = clients.GroupBy(n => n.ClientType)
            .Select(n => new TotalPerType { Type = n.Key, Total = n.Count() })
            .ToList();
```

was returning:

```
Landlord   1
Clients.   5
```

My investigation shows the problem with the key. When I added a complex key using UserId and ClientType, EF started to return the same value as SQL server.